# How to Active second tab on product detail page when product detail page is opened?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How to active 2nd tab name **'More Information'** in product view page on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with change of sort order attributes value.

Add the below code to your theme catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

or file under your theme Magento_Catalog -> layout -> catalog_product_view.xml 
and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

This will change the sequence of your tabs and More Information tab will be at first place.

Comment: I only want to open 2nd Tabs without change the sort order